# Netlogo - set background shape

Tags: netlogo

How can I add a static shape to the model`s world ?
I know that in order to set an image I can do `import-pcolors "Image.png"`
Can I do the same with the shape?
Currently in order to add such a shape I do:

```
ask patches with [((pxcor > 4) and (pxcor < 9) and
                 (pycor > -11) and (pycor < 5))] 

[ set pcolor white
    set plabel-color black
    ask turtle 0 [
      setxy 8 2
      set color blue
      set shape "circle"]
]
```

Comment: If you mean a shape as in a turtle shape, you can change the shape/size/color/position of a turtle using the command center, then use `export-view` to send that to a png, then use `import-colors` with that new file as you have been doing to get a complex shape as the patch colors.

Comment: I don't really understand from your description what your goal is, but, perhaps you're looking for `stamp`? It leaves an image of a turtle behind in the drawing layer.